# Obtaining the number of elements in details with Master-Detail view with database as source

Tags: c#, database, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I created a Master-Detail view using two `DataGridView`s with `BindingSource`s connected to the same database. Database has two tables and I established a Master-Detail view between them following a [Microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.100).aspx). Here is the code responsible for it:

```
private void GetData()
{
try
{
    // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
    // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
    // database accessible to your system.
    String connectionString =
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" +
        "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    // Create a DataSet.
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    // Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.
    SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new
        SqlDataAdapter("select * from Customers", connection);
    masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Customers");

    // Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.
    SqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter = new
        SqlDataAdapter("select * from Orders", connection);
    detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Orders");

    // Establish a relationship between the two tables.
    DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("CustomersOrders",
        data.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
        data.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);
    data.Relations.Add(relation);

    // Bind the master data connector to the Customers table.
    masterBindingSource.DataSource = data;
    masterBindingSource.DataMember = "Customers";

    // Bind the details data connector to the master data connector,
    // using the DataRelation name to filter the information in the 
    // details table based on the current row in the master table. 
    detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
    detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "CustomersOrders";
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the " +
        "connectionString variable with a connection string that is " +
        "valid for your system.");
}
}
```

and it works very well. Next I added a custom column to the master and following the same tutorial used this snippet to edit the master view's appearance.

```
// Changes how cells are displayed depending on their columns and values.
private void masterGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the background to red for negative values in the Balance column.
    if (masterGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("CustomColumn"))
    {

            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkRed;            
    }
}
```

Now I would like to get the count of rows in each detail view when a different master is chosen. I will add this to the custom column. This is where I get stuck. How do I access the count from the cell formatter event in the last snippet? I have access to both views and data sources too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've loaded your data and added your custom column, try using the [DataRow.GetChildRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3y2s99c(v=vs.110).aspx) method to count the number of rows in the details view. This will set the initial values:

```
DataSet ds = this.masterBindingSource.DataSource as DataSet;
string tableName = this.masterBindingSource.DataMember;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.masterDataGridView.Rows)
{
    row.Cells["CustomColumn"].Value = ds.Tables[tableName].Rows[row.Index].GetChildRows(ds.Relations[0]).Length;
}
```

---

If you will be allowing the user to add/delete rows from the details view, I would suggest first setting the following <sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup>:

```
this.masterDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.detailsDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

From there you need to attach to `RowChanged` and `RowDeleting` events on the details `DataTable`:

```
ds.Tables["Orders"].RowChanged += Details_RowChanged;
ds.Tables["Orders"].RowDeleting += Details_RowChanged;
```

In that event handler we will again set the master row's custom column value based on the `GetChildRows` method. Special considerations:

- For deleted rows, that count will not yet reflect the deletion. We will account for this.
- For added rows, unless you've already set the parent row at add-time, you'll need to handle this here.

With that said:

```
private void Details_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    int change = 0;
    DataSet ds = this.masterBindingSource.DataSource as DataSet;

    if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
    {
        DataRow parent = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Customers"].Rows)
        {
            if (dr["CustomerID"].Equals(e.Row["CustomerID"]))
            {
                parent = dr;
                break;
            }
        }

        e.Row.SetParentRow(parent);
    }
    else if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Delete)
    {
        change = -1;
    }

    DataRow row = e.Row.GetParentRow(ds.Relations[0]);
    int index = ds.Tables["Customers"].Rows.IndexOf(row);

    this.masterDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["CustomColumn"].Value = row.GetChildRows(ds.Relations[0]).Length + change;
}
```

---

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> <sup>Adding rows should be done programmatically - `DataTable.Rows.Add(params object[] values)` - when adding to a data bound `DataGridView`.</sup>